# Xamarin Studio runs into exception when opening ASP.NET C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, xamarin, xamarin-studio

All,

I'm new to ASP.NET programming, and am trying to do some examples to get started. I'm doing this in Xamarin 4.0.8(build 2). When I try and open up the `Default.aspx` file (generated when the project is created), I encounter the following exception warning:

```
System.Exception: System.Web assembly name not found for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5
at MonoDevelop.AspNet.WebTypeContext.GetSystemWebDom(TargetRuntime runtime, TargetFramework targetFramework)
at MonoDevelop.AspNet.WebTypeContext.GetSystemWebDom(AspNetAppProject project)
at MonoDevelop.AspNet.WebTypeContext..ctor(AspNetAppProject project)
at MonoDevelop.AspNet.Parser.DocumentReferenceManager..ctor(AspNetAppProject project)
at MonoDevelop.AspNet.Gui.AspNetEditorExtension.OnParsedDocumentUpdated()
at MonoDevelop.XmlEditor.Gui.BaseXmlEditorExtension.<Initialize>b__0(Object , EventArgs )
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Document.OnDocumentParsed(EventArgs e)
at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Document.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e <>c__DisplayClass20.<StartReparseThread>b__1b(Object , EventArgs )
at Gtk.Application.InvokeCB.Invoke()
at GLib.Timeout.TimeoutProxy.Handler()
```

Furthermore, I receive this exception later on:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at MonoDevelop.AspNet.Gui.AspNetEditorExtension.OnParsedDocumentUpdated()
at MonoDevelop.XmlEditor.Gui.BaseXmlEditorExtension.<Initialize>b__0(Object , EventArgs )
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Document.OnDocumentParsed(EventArgs e)
at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Document.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<>c__DisplayClass20.<StartReparseThread>b__1b(Object , EventArgs )
at Gtk.Application.InvokeCB.Invoke()
at GLib.Timeout.TimeoutProxy.Handler()
```

Eventually it gets to the point where the IDE has to close.

I tried switching the targeted framework from Mono/.NET 4.0 to Mono/.NET 4.5 to no avail.

It seems like it just isn't finding the System.Web library. How do I point it there?

Comment: can you not add a reference to System.Web bysaying right click and add reference?

Comment: There are a lot of missing things in Mono 4.5 System.Web: http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.5&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Web - Can you compile the solution without any error?

Comment: Smartis, I assume that you mean in Visual Studio? Most likely yes, as the example is nothing more than an HTML form.

Comment: what OS are you using? what version of mono are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The error is misguiding, at least on windows machines. You need to enable .NET framework 2.0 and 3.0 in order to get rid of this error. Also, if you need to keep your .aspx and designer.aspx.cs in sync regarding controls.